# How to access dictionary like structure in Protovis (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, protovis

I am trying to visualize a flickr dataset using protovis. I do understand the visualization part, but i have a question about accessing the data however. I was provided an example visualization and it accesses the data as folllowing:

```
var data = pv.range(250).map(function(row) {
    return {
        views: parseInt(Data.data(row, 2)), //refers to the 4 row and 2nd collumn in CSV
        users: Data.data(row, 6),
        date:  Data.data(row, 8))), //more collumns excist but for now we only use these
     };
  });
```

As i understand a part of the data set is now stored in the variable data, namely views, users and date. Is this variable able to beaccessed like a dictionary?

What i am trying to do is checking whether there are date on which one user occurs more than 2 times. I thought of looping through the var data as follows:

```
dateUserDict {};

for (d=0; d < data.date.length; d++ ){
    for (i=0; i < data.users.length; i++ ){
        for (j=0; j < data.users.length; j++){
            if (data.users[i] == data.users[j]){
                userCounter++ //this should count the number of occurences of a specific user on a specific date
                dateUserDict[data.date] = [data.user][userCounter]}
        }
    }
}
```

This does not seem to work. I am trying to store the events (the number of times a user occurs on a specific date) in a dictionary. If i get the dictionary as described i can easily visualise the whole thing. But it is this conversion from the first dict (data) to the second (dateUserDict) which bugs me!

Any help or a push is highly appreciated!

Thanks

jorrit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you provided will product a Javascript array of objects.

```
var data = pv.range(250).map(function(row) {
  return {
    views: parseInt(Data.data(row, 2)), //refers to the 4 row and 2nd collumn in CSV
    users: Data.data(row, 6),
    date:  Data.data(row, 8))), //more collumns excist but for now we only use these
  };
});
```

The result will look something like this:

```
var data = [ {views:10, users: 9, date: '09/13/1975'}, ... ]
```

So instead of using data.users.length, use data.length, and instead of data.users[i], you should be using data[i].users, etc.

Comment: sorry for the late reaction,  but you're right.

2d objects always confuse me ;)